# How to send push notifications in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, event-handling, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a game management app with flutter.
I should implement a feature where when a user performs a specific action (communicate a result of a game played), the opposing user gets a notification so that he can confirm that result.

in short, the registration of the results of the matches takes place exclusively by the users.

The problem arises when I have to understand how to send this specific notification, in fact with Firebase it is possible to send notifications but from what I understand it is not possible to implement an event and event handler system, that would be right for me.

in fact, I can choose to restrict the group of devices to which to send a notification or schedule the time but not make this process automatic from what I understand.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Building a system like you are describing is totally doable with Firebase.

You need to proceed step by step so you can understand each process and make it work.
In your case if I understand correctly, at the end of the game the user is prompted (or needs to go there himself) to a ScoreCard in order to fill in the results.
Once the results inserted, the other player/team receives a notifications so he can validate / invalidate the score.

> Front end prompt > User Action > Notification for other User.

Looking at it like that is a simple messaging process, that can occur both ways.

Now if we look at how the notification system works, what you need to do is first to save the user FCM Token to the user model you are storing. Meaning, when logging in your app you call the `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` method and add it to the user. (There can be multiple tokens if the users logs in multiple devices).

Now that you have the identifier that allows the send of a notification to a specific user you can add a document to your `notifications` collection that will contain the userID to send the notification to and the content of the notification in Firebase.

Lastly you can add a FirebaseCloudFunction that listen to the documents in the `notifications` collections updates and trigger a notification send to the FCM Token of the specified userId.